# How can I check if a user is logged in as (user)? - PassportJS

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I'm trying to check if a user is logged in with a specific username, say "coolguy123". How can I do that? I have the registering and the checking if user logged in all set up.

And for the reason why I'm doing this, it's simple: to redirect the client to a user-specific dashboard that, for example, (like a bank), shows the balance an account of a certain user.

Comment: why do you need to redirect the client to a user-specific dashboard? Can't  you implement a RBAC for that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the `user` property that is attached to the request object after logging in. You can then add a condition to your route.

Example:

```js
if (req.user.username === 'coolguy123') return res.redirect('/dashboard')
```

It's also possible to use a single dashboard route. Then for the user specific information you can then have API requests to the backend from the dashboard page to populate the user data.